# Using ASP.NET MVC3 code inside a static-html CMS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, coldfusion, content-management-system

We have a content management system here which basically pushes out static html pages. It's not tied to any particular programming language leaving each area the ability to use whatever they want depending on the web server they are pushing their pages out to. My area's web server runs both ColdFusion and Asp.NET, and I've been developing my first MVC3 application. It is just about finished and now I need to link up a public web form to my application's "Create" action. This basic HTML web form will be outside of MVC3 and Visual Studio and I'm guessing will reside inside of our CMS and it will pass the data onto my MVC3 application's controller. I am not sure how to go about this, can I just look at the html souce of my Create View code and then copy/paste the same HTML to my separate CMS page? Is there a way to "include" the Create View into my CMS, which doesn't even know ASP.NET exists?

If you need specifics, we're using Hannon Hill's Cascade Server. I've done plenty of pages using ColdFusion code to do html web forms but don't know where to begin using ASP.NET instead of ColdFusion inside of this CMS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as ColdFusion is concerned, it is just writing files. Could you just have it create a .aspx file that includes the relevant ASP.NET code?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I need. My question then becomes how different (syntax-wise) is writing aspx files as opposed to everything I've learned and done so far with MVC3? I didn't think I could do any kind of MVC stuff with this. Can I write the same C# code and use helpers or do I need to learn basic ASP syntax?

Comment: I believe you can create generic templates with Razor (MVC3). Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368815/razor-views-as-email-templates.