# Razor type ViewEngine

Tags: .net, reflection, razor

In short, I'd like to have a template that looks something like:

> Dear @model.Firstname @model.Surname

I'd like to feed that into a method together with a prepopulated model like:

```
private String Transform(String Template, object model)  
{

}
```

I then want to find all the places in the template starting with @ and replace it with the data contained in the supplied model.

The model would look something like:

```
    public class Receipt
    {
        public String Firstname { get; set; }
        public String Surname { get; set; }
        ...
```

I'm sure I should be able to get this done using reflection. How do I load the model object as a type of Model and then access the data it holds?

They do it in Razor, so I assume it must be possible.

Comment: You can use Razor itself.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368815/razor-views-as-email-templates) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer to this is to take a look at the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) over at codeplex.

```
  string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";  
  string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

It really is that easy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MvcMailer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145629/Announcing-MvcMailer-Send-Emails-Using-ASP-NET-MVC), which uses Razor views to compose emails.